# Getting error running spring boot application using -jar

Tags: spring, spring-boot

This question has been asked over and over, however I couldn't find my answer. I have an application using spring boot, which intellij can run it without any issue, however `java -jar echohostname.jar` give me this error:

```
Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean
```

Here is my Main class:

```
public class ApplicationMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(SpringConfiguration.class);
        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = builder.run(args);


    }
```

This is my Controller class:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("getSigarProxy")
    private SigarProxy sigarProxy;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hostname", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hostName() throws SigarException {
        return "HELLO THERE";
        //return sigarProxy.getNetInfo().getHostName();
    }
}
```

And this is spring configuration class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("controller")
public class SpringConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer getPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public Sigar getSigar() {
        return new Sigar();
    }

    @Bean
    public SigarProxy getSigarProxy() {
        return SigarProxyCache.newInstance(getSigar(), 1000);
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public HttpHeaders getHttpHeaders() {
        return new HttpHeaders();
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public AsyncRestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
        return new AsyncRestTemplate();
    }

}
```

POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>echoHostname</groupId>
    <artifactId>echoHostname</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.fusesource</groupId>
            <artifactId>sigar</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


</project>
```

**UPDATED MAIN:**

```
public class ApplicationMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(SpringConfiguration.class, args);


    }
}
```

**UPDATED POM:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>echoHostname</groupId>
    <artifactId>echoHostname</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.fusesource</groupId>
            <artifactId>sigar</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you using a maven ? in this case please add to the question the pom file

Comment: @reos updated the question with pom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add class level `@SpringBootApplication` annotation in `ApplicationMain.java`

Add the below plugin in your `pom.xml`. Build the maven project and execute the jar command

```
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

This page has more information on maven assembly plugin - https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html

Comment: Yes I did that also, but doing that cause intellij also to give the same error

Comment: Try replacing the code in ApplicationMain.java with ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(ApplicationMain.class, args);

Comment: Still the same error, it runs in intellij but not with -jar command

Comment: What is the exact jar command you are using? I just tried in eclipse and it works.

Comment: I have put the exact command in the question `java -jar echohostname.jar`

Comment: I edited my answer. Add the plugin in <build><plugins> ... </plugins></build> and let me know if it works

Comment: Yes it finally worked with the plugin! I was running another jar file by mistake thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In a spring-boot project, you need that the parent pom be

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

You can remove the spring dependencies, like context, core and beans.

Add to the pom

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And build the jar again.

Comment: just did that, still everything is fine running the application in intellij, but not running jar file

Comment: hmm that's weird. I use eclipse and your code run ok. Please update your question with your actual pom.

Comment: Try adding @EnableAutoConfiguration to your SpringConfiguration class

Comment: Nope didn't work. It is weird that everything is fine inside intellij but not jar

Comment: Yes, it's weird. I can run the jar in the command line and inside eclipse. I don't know probably running a maven clean and then a maven install could help.

Comment: Finally could run it with the plugin that localhost999 put. It seems the jar that intellij was creating had some issues, but after creating the jar with the plugin now everything is fine. Thanks for you time